# Host header's configuration (Windows IIS)

Tags: domain, subdomain, iis

I've moved to a new host provider and on my last host provider they'd configured all sub-domains that don't exist to map to my base domain.

Aka,

`products.searisen.com` doesn't exist, but it would call `searisen.com` and then my default file would handle the request for it.

My new provider has me manage the IIS myself and I'm a newb at it.

I'm using IIS Manager.

**Edit**: It's a shared site.

**Edit**: The shared site is on a Windows 2008 IIS7 server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for IIS6: Right click the web site in IIS Manager, select properties from the context menu, on the web site tab click that Advanced button next to the ip address field, in the Advanced Web Site Identification peoperties click the ADD button, set the ip address, port, and host header value, click OK on all properties pages until the web site properties pages are closed.

Comment: It's a shared site.  There is no properties on right click context-menu.  I've sent an email to support, hopefully they can set this for me - thanks for the reply.

Comment: That doesn't make sense: if you have control over IIS Manager, you have control over your host headers.  Please, try again -- if it's IIS 7x, you'll see a "Bindings..." entry in the right-click context menu for the Website. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I'm sure this is the right answer, but my host provider won't modify the host headers :(  They want me to check something else, *URL Rewrite module in IIS7* which I'll ask a new question about after googling around first.

Comment: @gravyface There's no Bindings option on the Actions menu, there are only View Applications and View Virtual Directories.

Comment: right-click on the site under Sites on the left.  It's there.

Answer (score 0):

If your DNS provider allows it, add an A record for ***.searisen.com** pointing at the same IP address for **searisen.com**

Alternately, add a CNAME record for ***.searisen.com** with its value set to **searisen.com**

~MBT

Comment: Yeah, turns out I have a shared IP and I can't do it.  Otherwise that is the thing to do.